# Unable to get names of selected files from file selector

Tags: jquery, typescript, forms

I'm creating a NodeJS project in Typescript in which I have a "file" input type - that is used to select and upload files. I want to be able to get the names of the files in Typescript as soon as they are selected by the user even before they are uploaded. For that, I have written a little code that is not working.

Here's the HTML for choosing the file.

```
<form id=\"" + this.id + "\" accept-charset=\"utf-8\" method=\"post\" action=\"/upload\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\">
<input id=\"inp\" type=\"file\" name=\"userfile\" multiple=\"multiple\" />
</form>
```

Here's the event which should get fired when the change is made:

```
$("input[id=inp]").change(function () {
   alert("Changed");
   /*for (var i = 0; $("#" + this.id + "input").get(0).files.length; ++i) {
       alert(i + ". Name : " + this.JQuerySelector().get(0).files[i].name);
   }*/});
```

This event is not getting fired. I've written some code for extracting selected filenames which I cant test because the "change" event wouldn't occur when files are selected (see commented code in change function). I've tried adding event handlers to the form and the individual input and select them by either the name or the id. But it doesn't get called.
I got my code from this page:

http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gSBCd/

Additionally, I'm also looking for ways to:

1. Hide the "Choose files" and the list of selected files next to it button and start the selection from other custom build buttons.
2. Be able to extract the names of selected files - every time the selection is made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `input[id=inp]` element are created dynamically you need to use event delegation to register event handlers to these elements.

When you use `$('input[id=inp]').change(....);` to register an event handler it will register the handle to only those elements which are already present in the dom at the time of the code execution, in you case since these elements are created after that the handlers will not get attached to the newly created elements

Try with this

```
$(document).on('change','input[id=inp]',function() {

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gSBCd/93/)

Comment: Thanks. And can you also make a suggestion to my questions in the end?